# Problems with the complex square root

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, radicals

I have a problem understanding the following procedure. (
It's from a script)

Consider the domain C[0,$\infty$) and the branch of the logarithm given by

$ log(z)=ln(|z|)+i \cdot arg(z)$ ,with $arg(z) \in(0,2\pi)$.

Then we find: $z^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{|z|} e^{i arg(z)/2}$, where $arg(z^{\frac{1}{2}}) \in (0,\pi)$
The square root of any complex number that is not a positive real then lies in the upper halfplane and in this case we find $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=i$

I don't understand why the last one follows. Why applies $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=i$ ?

I know I can write: $-1^{\frac{1}{2}}= e^{\frac{1}{2}ln(|-1|)+arg(-1)}=e^{\frac{1}{2}arg(-1)}$ and arg(-1) ist $\pi$ and with that the upper equation would be correct....BUT that's actually wrong, since $\pi$ is not in the domain of arg. Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: What do you mean by _script_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only argument of $-1$ in $(0,2\pi)$ is $\pi$. Therefore, by that definition we have$$z^{1/2}=\sqrt1e^{i\pi/2}=i.$$

Comment: okay i guess i understand. But what about the following: Can i find a branch, for which $1^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $-1^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are defined and  $-1^{\frac{1}{2}}=-i$?

Comment: Yes: for each $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{\lambda i\mid\lambda\in(-\infty,0]\}$ let $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ be the only argument of $z$ in $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$. Then define $z^{1/2}$ as $-\sqrt{|z|}e^{i\operatorname{arg}(z)/2}$.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Unfortunately I don't understand that. In this case we would be have arg(-1) =! - $\pi$   and in the first case we had  arg(-1) = $\pi$.  I do not understand how the definition area changes the sign of $\pi$.  Sorry I'm a little confused.

Comment: I think that you missed the minus sign in the definition of $z^{1/2}$.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that. But why can I just define a minus there? And why do I choose exactly this domain? I think my problem is still the same and only in a different place.

Comment: The minus sign is there s that $(-1)^{1/2}=-i$.

Comment: Yes, I see what the sign is used for. But I still don't understand why I can just change the definition compared to the first case. I think maybe it has something to do with the Domain (-$\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$) you chose?

Comment: It's so that both $1$ and $-1$ belong to the domain of $z\mapsto z^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it